# Is it possible to specify a MSBuild property on the command line which references another property?

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-4.0

For example given a project `quickie.vcxproj`, to build it under `c:\output\c` without specifying the project name explicitly:

`msbuild /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Debug /p:PlatformToolset=v100  quickie\quickie.vcxproj /p:OutDir=c:\output\c\$(MSBuildProjectName)\`

The result is a directory `c:\output\c\$(MSBuildProjectName)`

Required result is: `c:\output\c\quickie`

Attemping with `c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Exceeding thirty characters